# ! Package amsmath Error: \begin{gather} allowed only in paragraph mode

Tags: equations, amsmath, paragraphs, alignment, rmarkdown

I need to align the following equation in R markdown:

```
$$\begin{gather*}
\hat{SalePrice} =2016.923+54.269SquareFeet+23246.083Baths+16761.402Bedrooms\\
-41955.452winter1-7486.937age2+4077.030age3+12506.082Bedrooms*winter1\\
-10028.711Bedrooms*age2-26555.181Bedrooms*age3
\end{gather*}$$
```

But this error prevents from getting pdf file:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{gather} allowed only in paragraph mode.
```

Comment: Welcome tex.sx  Your error here is to wrap the `gather` inside `$$` which is math mode.  "Paragraph mode" is just ordinary text.  `gather` is a self-standing display structure that automatically enters math mode.

Answer (score 2):

As @barbarabeeton has already pointed out in a comment, its a mistake to encase the `gather*` environment in a `$$ ... $$` wrapper. Hence, get rid ride of both instances of `$$`. The code then compiles; the result is shown in the first equation in the following screenshot.

While the code compiles, the output doesn't exactly look attractive. To improrve the overall look, you could render the variable names in upright letter2, replace all instance of `*` with `\times`, and use `\widehat` instead of `\hat`.

The "look" of the equation could be enhanced further by replacing the `gather*` environment with an `align*` environment and setting suitable alignment points `&`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath} % for gather* and align* environments
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % how to display variable names

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\hat{SalePrice} =2016.923+54.269SquareFeet+23246.083Baths+16761.402Bedrooms\\
-41955.452winter1-7486.937age2+4077.030age3+12506.082Bedrooms*winter1\\
-10028.711Bedrooms*age2-26555.181Bedrooms*age3
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
\widehat{\vn{SalePrice}} =2016.923+54.269\,\vn{SquareFeet}
  +23246.083\,\vn{Baths}+16761.402\,\vn{Bedrooms}\\
-41955.452\,\vn{winter1}-7486.937\,\vn{age2}+4077.030\,\vn{age3}
  +12506.082\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{winter1}\\
-10028.711\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{age2}
  -26555.181\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{age3}
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
\widehat{\vn{SalePrice}} 
&=2016.9+54.3\,\vn{SquareFeet}+23246.1\,\vn{Baths}
 +16761.4\,\vn{Bedrooms}\\
&\quad-41955.5\,\vn{winter1}-7486.9\,\vn{age2}+4077.0\,\vn{age3}
 +12506.1\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{winter1}\\
&\quad-10028.7\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{age2}
 -26555.2\,\vn{Bedrooms}\times\vn{age3}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```